# ZipFS failed to load dwasmod.dll

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have an Azure app service that is hosting an Angular .NET Core 7 app, and I am getting an error for "Failed to load dwasmod.dll".  From what I am finding online is basically my project is referencing this dll and I just need to include it in my project.  But from what I can tell, I can't find it in my project.  The staging site works fine and when I view the staging directory in Azure, I do not see this dll.

Does anyone know where this dll may be referenced and do I need to add it to my project?